# NFC Software developement kit NFC wrapper sample

Tags: c#

When I Open the NFC wrapper sample code on my desktop which is a 32 bit operating system the program works by stating "SCM_NFC.DLL successfully loaded". But when I tried it on my laptop a 64 bit operating system it states "NFC Wrapper not found Be sure that the file SCM_NFC.dll is present in the search path.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On the configuration manager of Visual Studio make sure to choose x86 as the target platform. The program itself needs  to runs as a 32bit application for the path to be properly resolved.